# Check if submit IMAGE was clicked via Request.Form

Tags: asp.net, html, webforms

How do I check if a submit IMAGE was clicked via Request.Form?

The following checks if a submit BUTTON was clicked via Request.Form by returning the value of the submit button if clicked:

```
<form action="Default.aspx" runat="server" method="post" id="newform">
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit!" runat="server" />
</form>

<%
if (Request.Form["submit"] != null) //TRUE
{
    Response.Write("Submit button pushed");
}

Response.Write(Request.Form["submit"]); //Returns "Submit!"
%>
```

The following checks if a submit IMAGE was clicked via Request.Form, but it DOESN'T return any value after the image was clicked:

```
<form action="Default.aspx" runat="server" method="post" id="newform">
<input type="image" id="subimg" src="solar_image.gif" alt="Can't show image" value="Submit Image!" runat="server"/>
</form>

<%
if (Request.Form["subimg"] != null) //FALSE
{
    Response.Write("Image Submit button clicked!");
}

Response.Write(Request.Form["subimg"]); //Doesn't return "Submit Image!"  
%>
```

Comment: In what browser are you seeing this? Does it work the same in other browsers?

Comment: I've tried IE and Firefox.
Same result as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code works for me in IE 9 and Chrome. Only way I can replicate is when using the Firefox as a browser.

This link sheds more light on the issues [Firefox 4.0 beta — as well as IE and Opera — do not send name/value for input type=”image”; only .x and .y coordinates are sent.](http://www.onenaught.com/posts/382/firefox-4-change-input-type-image-only-submits-x-and-y-not-name)

The following check works in every browser I've tested:

```
//Checking both x and y co-ordinates to be doubly safe
Request.Form["subimg.x"] != null && Request.Form["subimg.y"] != null
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/Input#compat-desktop):

> "Gecko 2.0 only sends x and y coordinates when clicked, not longer the
>   name/value of the element"

Try printing out Request.Form. If there's x and y in the response, you can detect that an image was clicked that way instead.